Поиск по предикату в колоночных СУБД
Упрощённо таблицу, хранящую данные поколоночно можно представить как отдельный файл под каждый столбец (поправляйте, если не прав), что позволяет эффективнее работать запросам, которые возвращают лишь несколько столбцов, читаю только их (а не всю строку, как в row-формате).
Но как работает поиск по предикатам в таких ситуциях?
Запрос формата select t.col1 from Table as t where t.col1 > 10 мне понятен, просто проверка условия.
Но как работает запрос формата select t.col1 from Table as t where t.col2 > 10 ? как обеспечивается связь значений col2 и col1 ? Это что-то в духе "50-ое значение col2 удовлетворяет условию - возьми 50-е значение col1 и верни пользователю" ?
Вероятно, для разных СУБД ответ может разниться - меня базово устроит ответ для любой системы. Если он также будет актуален для Greenplum - будет здорово.

Формат хранения данных на диске у каждой СУБД свой и лезть туда не стоит. Реляционные СУБД при работе с таблицами оперируют строкой, а не полями. Ваш пример читается так: Выбери строки, где условие выполняется и выведи перечисленные поля.

@SwaD , Меня в данном вопросе интересуют сугубо СУБД, оперирующие колонками: Vertica, Clickhouse, Greenplum'овские append-optimized table итд

Column-oriented DBMS - тут описано устройство, кратко, но нормально. По найденному значению в первой колонке будет взят индекс, а по индексу извлечено значение из другой колонки. / Но это лишь теория. А конкретное устройство у каждой СУБД может сильно отличаться.

@Lobster25 "Меня в данном вопросе интересуют сугубо СУБД, оперирующие колонками". А не бывает таких субд, они бесполезны. А те что бывают - всего навсего выдают колонки за строки. Вы можете любую табличку взять и переписать так, что колонки станут столбцами, и наоборот тоже работает. Суть тут в том, что колонки никому не нужны, на уровне программирования и устройств субд - колонки не нужны. Потому что всё всегда в субд - это строки. Почему так? А потому что операции со строками сильно быстрее работают.
